# Is there a nice closed form for set cover on this quite symmetrical setup

Tags: graph-theory

This question arises from trying to improve some sort of random code, the specifics don't matter.

Suppose that we have two integers $a$ and $b$ such that $b$ divides $a$ (we may assume that they are powers of two). Let $W$ be a set of size $a$, let $C$ be a collection of subsets of $W$, each of size $b$, and there are $a$ of those. Suppose further that each $x\in W$ appears in exactly $b$ sets in $C$.

Can we guarantee that there is a set cover with $a/b$ sets ? They would have to be disjoint and of course this would be optimal. A weaker question that would also be enough is, if $k$ is the number of sets in a minimal set cover, can we show that $k = O(p(\log a) a/b)$ for some polynomial $p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the strong version of the question, the answer is negative. Take three disjoint copies of the [Fano plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane). We get $a=21$ points, covered by $21$ sets of size $b=3$, such that every point appears in exactly $3$ sets. However, each Fano plane takes $3$ sets to cover, so the minimum set cover has $9$ sets, not $\frac ab = 7$.

Or, if we want a counterexample where $a$ and $b$ are powers of $2$, take $a=8$ and $b=2$. If we let $W = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ and $C = \big\{\{1,2\}, \{2,3\}, \{1,3\}, \{4,5\},\{5,6\}, \{6,7\}, \{7,8\}, \{4,8\}\big\}$, then we cannot cover $W$ with only $4$ sets from $C$; we need at least $2$ sets to cover $\{1,2,3\}$ and at least $3$ sets to cover $\{4,5,6,7,8\}$.

Graph-theoretically, the $b=2$ case is about trying to find a perfect matching in an $2$-regular $a$-vertex graph. In such a graph, every component is a cycle, and even a single odd cycle ruins things for us. In the worst case, almost all components are $3$-cycles, and we need roughly $\frac23a = \frac43 \cdot \frac ab$ sets in our cover.

So in the case $b=2$, we get an $O(\frac ab)$ bound on $k$, but it's unclear what will happen as $b$ increases.